# I am getting Plotchar error on inputing size

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot a star using plotchar by inputing size from user.

I used the following code

```
sizeOption = input(title="Star Size", type=input.string,
 options=["Auto", "Huge", "Large", "Normal", "Small", "Tiny"],
 defval="Auto")
labelSize = (sizeOption == "Huge") ? size.huge :
 (sizeOption == "Large") ? size.large :
 (sizeOption == "Small") ? size.small :
 (sizeOption == "Tiny") ? size.tiny :
 (sizeOption == "Auto") ? size.auto :
     size.normal
Bullish=close>open
plotchar(Bullish,title="Bullish",char = '*', color = color.green , location = location.abovebar, transp = 0,size = labelSize)
```

I am getting the following error
"Cannot call 'plotchar' with 'size'=input.string. The argument should be of type: const string"

I need help to resolve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways around this. Either create plotchar() calls for each size or to use labels instead. Auto/Huge/Large/Normal are usually not very useful with plotchar though, so you may just need to code for small and tiny.

```
plotchar(sizeOption == "Tiny" ? Bullish : na, char = "*", size = size.tiny)
plotchar(sizeOption == "Auto" ? Bullish : na, char = "*", size = size.auto)
etc..
```